# Syntax error (while)

Tags: python

Why does my program tell me that I have a syntax error with while?

```
f=open(input('Sisesta faili nimi: ')
while True:
    if f.readline()=='':
        break
    else:
        tekst=int(f.readline())
        print(tekst,'on '.strip())
        if tekst%2==0:
            print('paarisarv')
        else:
            print('paaritu arv')
f.close()
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a missing ) that any good editor would have pointed out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing parentheses:

```
f=open(input('Sisesta faili nimi: ')
f=open(input('Sisesta faili nimi: '))
```

Also you are not cleaning or validating the input from the user. A user could type anything.

Comment: Thanks! How did I miss it...